# Oracle Apex conditional icons on values in classic report

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a follow up question based on this answer which is string based:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556608/221270

How to achieve the same conditional color and icon formatting but based on a value:

```
SELECT task_name,
start_date,
status,
CASE status
  WHEN > 50 THEN 'fa-clock-o is-open'
  WHEN > 100 THEN 'fa-check-circle is-closed'
  WHEN > 150 THEN 'fa-exclamation-circle is-holding'
  WHEN > 200 THEN 'fa-exclamation-triangle is-pending'
END status_icon,
CASE status
  WHEN > 10 THEN 'red'
  WHEN > 50 THEN 'green'
  WHEN > 150 THEN 'pink'
  WHEN > 200 THEN 'orange'
END icon_color,
assigned_to
FROM eba_ut_chart_tasks
ORDER BY 2
```

If I use the code above I got this error:

> ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 10, column 1: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: The Syntax should be `CASE WHEN...` such as `CASE WHEN status > 50...` .... **not** `CASE <expression> WHEN...` as in the current case

Comment: Correct, of course. If you answer, I could accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current syntax is wrong. You need to take the `status` column between each `WHEN` and `THEN` clauses in order to get boolean expressions such as

```sql
SELECT task_name,
       start_date,
       status,
       CASE 
         WHEN status > 50 THEN
          'fa-clock-o is-open'
         WHEN status > 100 THEN
          'fa-check-circle is-closed'
         WHEN status > 150 THEN
          'fa-exclamation-circle is-holding'
         WHEN status > 200 THEN
          'fa-exclamation-triangle is-pending'
       END status_icon,
       CASE 
         WHEN status > 10 THEN
          'red'
         WHEN status > 50 THEN
          'green'
         WHEN status > 150 THEN
          'pink'
         WHEN status > 200 THEN
          'orange'
       END icon_color,
       assigned_to
  FROM eba_ut_chart_tasks
 ORDER BY 2
```